# mysql - How to execute block of code within an IF statement (but not in a procedure)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know there's better ways to version-track a database, but for the sake of argument... how could I make this method work.

I would simply like to have a table `db_version` with columns `v01`, `v02`, etc...
and have a block of code execute only if a certaing `vXX` doesnt exist.

For example:

```
IF NOT EXIST ( 
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME='db_version' AND column_name='v05'
 ) THEN
      ALTER TABLE ... 
      ALTER TABLE ...
      ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX ...
      ALTER TABLE db_version ADD column v05 int;  /* now this block wont be run next time */
 END IF;
```

Is this possible? All the examples I see online are only for being run inside a PROCEDURE.
How can I just execute this in regular sql script (`mysql -p < db_version.sql`)

Comment: You can't do that outside of a stored routine, see [manual, if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html): *The IF statement **for stored programs** implements a basic conditional construct.*

Comment: you could probably use case logic here.. but it would have to be for each alter table.